# Using sed to add a prefix to variable content in korn shell

Tags: variables, awk, sed, ksh

I'm trying to stay away from all run time temp files. I was able to replace all of them by a run time variable, but one command is giving me a hard time when I use the command with a variable.

rimco content: contains the file location

```
   /home/bim 
   /home/ram 
   /home/gps 
   /home/hdr 
   /home/pal
```

bim content: contains a set of numbers

```
28800,1536,14400,768
11100,12312,902,321
3044,1536,1290,334
3044,1536,1290,334
11100,12312,902,321
28800,1536,14400,768
```

The goal is to add a prefix to a variable `$output` if the number I'm looking for is found.    the line is stored in `$output` with a prefix `$dte`

```
dte="available" 
for f in $(cat rimco)
  do 
   out=`grep 768 $f`
     output+=`echo -e "\n$out"| sed "s/^/$dte,/"`
 done
```

Well, the result is unappealing,  **dte content,** is all over the place

```
available,
available,28800,1536,14400,768
available,28800,1536,14400,768available,
available,28800,1536,14400,768
available,28800,1536,14400,768available,
available,28800,1536,14400,768
available,28800,1536,14400,768available,
available,28800,1536,14400,768
available,28800,1536,14400,768available,
available,28800,1536,14400,768
available,28800,1536,14400,768
```

The goal is to get this

```
available,28800,1536,14400,768
available,28800,1536,14400,768
available,28800,1536,14400,768
available,28800,1536,14400,768
available,28800,1536,14400,768
available,28800,1536,14400,768
available,28800,1536,14400,768
available,28800,1536,14400,768
available,28800,1536,14400,768
available,28800,1536,14400,768
```

Any idea how to fix that?

thanks

Comment: What's the value of `$dte`? The first error is certainly using `echo -e "\n$out"` - just `echo "$out"` should get you closer to your goal.

Comment: Also, what's with the `+=` and what does the variable contain before you add something to it?

Comment: I'm tempted to vote as unclear because there are so many free variables. Could you [edit] this into a [mcve] please?

Comment: echo -e "\n$out" will output out content to the next line
+=  will concatenate to the content of the variable it's like 1+1

Comment: No, it will print an empty line which `sed` then adds a prefix to. If you want an empty line before the final output, print it there and then. Also `echo -e` will cause any escape codes in the value to be mangled outside of your control.

Comment: And I know what `+=` does; it only makes sense if the variable already contained something else. That's why I'm asking what you expect it to contain before this. It's not 1+1, it's *x* + 1 where *x* is still unknown.

Comment: like I said it will concatenate to the content, not sure if you read my response before posting, but 1+1 was just a metaphor to give you a visual idea. also you are wrong if you don't use echo -e and your grep returned more that 1 line it will be stored in one line because it's a variable and not a file.

Comment: I'm sorry, this sounds like you have fantasies about how these things work which would need a more detailed analysis before we can talk about how to fix your code.

Comment: @Driven what is the contents of $out from the zgrep?

Comment: $out contains a set of numbers  if the pattern matches what I'm looking for. in this case it will be 28800,1536,14400,768 because I'm grepping for 768

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my answer for many files to grep. With an extra variable *result* to concatenate and a grep to get rid of the empty line:

```
dte="available"
result="" 
for f in $(cat rimco)
  do 
     out=`grep 768 $f`
     output=`echo -e "$out" | sed "s/^/$dte,/"`
     result="$result\n$output"
 done

echo -e "$result" | grep -v "^$"
```

This returns:

```
available,28800,1536,14400,768
available,28800,1536,14400,768
available,28800,1536,14400,768
available,28800,1536,14400,768
available,28800,1536,14400,768
available,28800,1536,14400,768
available,28800,1536,14400,768
available,28800,1536,14400,768
available,28800,1536,14400,768
available,28800,1536,14400,768
```

Comment: bravissimo it's perfect you are a very smart cookie my friend. You broke down the concatenation process and added a new line, for the next cycle very good.
you do realized that you solved the problem with just one line:
 `result="$result\n$output"`. I'm not too concerned about the the first empty line, but this is it you nailed it.

Answer (score 0):

If you change your grep to a one liner it works (remove the for loop):

```
dte="available"
files=$(cat rimco)
out=`grep 768 $files`
output=`echo -e "$out" | sed "s/^.*:/$dte,/"`
echo -e "$output"
```

The sed now replaces the file name (result from grep) plus the colon : by the $dte string

Comment: you need /n if not it will store everything in one line if you grep return more that 1 match. you cant test  that with the small script I added in the description

Comment: @Driven I just changed my answer. The solution is now much more simple.

Comment: @Driven, you don't need the for loop. My answer shows the complete code.

Comment: yes!!! I do because there are 1000s of files to grep. rimco is the location holder it provides the file location for the grep.

Comment: also if  you don't concatenate it will overwrite `$output` content, during each loop cycle. You will only have the last grep result in the `$output `

Comment: I have added another answer that should fit your need to grep many files